# Let G be an inner direct product of subgroups H and K

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

Let $G$ be an inner direct product of subgroups $H$ and $K$.  Prove that the function $\phi : G \rightarrow H \times K$ such that $\phi (g) = (h,k)$ for $g = hk$, where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$, is injective and surjective.

Here's what I have:

Injectivity:  Let $h_1, h_2 \in H$ and $k_1, k_2 \in K$ such that $h_1k_1 = h_2k_2$.  WTS: $g_1 = g_2$.  If $\phi (g_1) = \phi (g_2) \Longleftrightarrow (h_1, k_1) = (h_2, k_2) \Longleftrightarrow h_1k_1 = h_2k_2 \Longleftrightarrow g_1 = g_2$.  so $\phi$ is injective.

Surjectivity: Consider some $g' \in G$.  Want to show that $\phi (g) = g'$.  And I'm stuck.

For the injectivity, I know I have a tendency to overcomplicate proofs, this may be the case.  For the surjectivity, I don't know what to take $g$ as in order to get some $g'$.

Comment: Since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, if $(h,k) \in H \times K$, then $h,k\in G$.  So, $hk \mapsto (h,k)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to consider the other direction: $H \times K \ni (h,k) \mapsto hk \in G$?

Comment: For surjectivity, you need to show that $\forall (h,k) \in H \times K$ you have a $g\in G$ such that $\phi(g)=(h,k)$

Answer (score 1):

A group $G$ is the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$ if $G=HK$, $H\cap K=1$, and $H,K$ are both normal subgroups of $G$.

Let $g\in G$.
Since $G=HK$, $g=hk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.
Hence $(h,k)\in H\times K$ where $\phi(g)=\phi(hk)=(h,k)$.

By the way, you can try to prove also that $\phi$ is a well-defined homomorphism so that we can conclude that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$.